# Caliburn Micro GoBack to previous page instance WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro.Core.2.0.1 on Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) application

All my ViewModels extends `Screen` as the base.

In my `MainView(Model)` I am able to navigate to a `SettingsView(Model)` with CM's INavigationService using

```
private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
public void Navigate()
{
    _navigationService.NavigateToViewModel<SettingsViewModel>(_param);
}
```

Then using the *Hardware Back Button* or

```
public void GoBack()
{
   _navigationService.GoBack();
}
```

I can navigate back to the MainView(Model).

It works; however, it does not work as I expected or wanted it to work.

When the GoBack (or Back button) is called, it generates a **new instance** of `MainView(Model)`. I want it to return to the **navigated from instance** of `MainView(Model)`.

I tried registering `MainViewModel` as a Singleton, this makes the `ViewModel` a singleton (and introduces some interesting issues); but the `View` is still recreated.

Any idea how to get the navigation to go back to the **navigated from instance**?

Comment: How are you setting up your ViewModels in `App.xaml.cs`, are you using `container.PerRequest<>` ?

Comment: @NeilTurner Yes for the most, except for the MainViewModel when I want it to make it a singleton as stated in the question then I use `_container.Singleton<MainViewModel>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `NavigationCacheMode` property of your view to `Enabled`.

For detailed information about this issue, please visit [this blog post](http://caliburnmicro.com/announcements/application-state-part-3/).

Comment: Thanks Frank, you're a legend :D